# "He threw around a slipper" -- Meaning of "threw around"?

Tags: intransitive-preposition

In the context of a young Singaporean boy having a temper tantrum, does this sentence mean the boy threw the slipper and picked up the slipper then threw it again?

> He threw around a slipper.

From [Boy throws tantrum on train, flings slipper around -- and even spits on man](http://singaporeseen.stomp.com.sg/singaporeseen/this-urban-jungle/boy-throws-tantrum-on-mrt-wails-and-throws-slipper-around-he-even-spits-on-man)

Comment: Beats me. Sounds very odd. You can only throw one slipper to one place at a time.  If there were several prople, they could throw it "around". But even then, you'd say they "threw the slipper around", not "they threw around the slipper". Can you give any more context —where you found this?

Comment: This is not the best site to ask *Questions that can be answered by a quick dictionary lookup (these are off topic on ELL, and there are many free dictionaries available online)*. This phrasal verb can be found in online dictionaries. Which dictionaries have you tried? Sometimes one has to try several. I tried two. I suggest looking the word up in this one: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I have attached the link, please check the "stomp" link.

Comment: @δοῦλος Hold on a minute old bean! I checked out that site you linked to and the definitions it gave. Neither of them fits the bill here :( In fact, that definition for this word is probably why the OP misunderstood!

Comment: @Araucaria The first definition at my link, and that definition's second example sentence is exactly how the verb is used in the article. In addition the first entry at the second definition fits how the verb is used in the story. In addition, the other **point** of my comment was that the OP should indicate what research he or she has done before posting.

Comment: @δοῦλος "**1. To scatter something by or as if by throwing**". Do you mean that definition?

Answer (score 3):

Your link points to a page with a video of a child having a temper tantrum on a train. I could not watch it because (a) the site was loading too slowly and (b) I couldn't stand listening to the child crying.

However, I can report that the child was (1) in the middle walking aisle on a train, (2) was having a temper tantrum, (3) and was, at various points, lying on his back *kicking his feet around*. This is all we need in order to understand the sentence.  The following is one *possible* scenario which could be considered "threw around a slipper".

- The child threw his slipper the first time. The first incident of "throwing" could have been from kicking his feet while he was on his back.  The slipper likely landed in the child's immediate vicinity. Note that *throw* has a connotation of using a hand to throw, but it's not strictly limited to this meaning in this case.
- The child retrieved his slipper and threw it again, this time with his hand.  This second throwing doesn't need to be anywhere in particular; it could have been thrown onto the floor near himself.
- At least one more throw is likely. If there was only the first two throws, "throw around" could be considered an exaggeration.

That is a kind of minimum scenario to which one might describe the incident with "threw around a slipper".  This is looking at the sentence as a [speech act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act) instead of just a declaritive statement.

**The meaning of *throw around* in this case is "to throw multiple times in an indiscriminate manner".**

Answer (score 2):

> 1. He threw around a slipper.
>
> QUESTION: Is it mean he throw the slipper and pick up the slipper then throw it again?

Yes, most likely that is probably what it was meant to mean. That is, he is throwing the slipper about repeatedly (such as in a room). Though, it is possible that he was able to always catch it before it ever lands on the ground or floor. A similar expression would be, *"He tossed around a slipper".*

Let's refer to this interpretation as **interpretation #A.**

NOTE: It is possible for there to be another interpretation or more. For instance, he could be throwing something around that slipper: Imagine that slipper tied to a rope from a branch of a tree, where the slipper is dangling in midair. A boy could throw a ball around that slipper, in an attempt to not hit it. But this is a rather unusual sort of context, and is very context dependent for its meaning. Let's refer to this interpretation as **interpretation #B.**

---

**SYNTAX:** As to the grammar that is involved in your example (with its most likely meaning), consider:

1. *"He threw **around** a slipper."* -- (OP's original)
2. *"He threw a slipper **around**."*
3. *"He threw around **it**."* -- (usually ungrammatical for **#A**; but good for **#B**)
4. *"He threw **it** around."*

As to the parsings:

- For interpretation **#A,** the word *"around"* is an intransitive preposition that is in the **particle** class, while the noun phrase *"a slipper"* is functioning as a clausal **direct object.**
- For interpretation **#B,** the word *"around"* is a preposition that is functioning as head of the **preposition phrase** *"around a slipper"*; and the noun phrase *"a slipper"* is functioning as the complement of that preposition *"around"*.

(Aside: For interpretation #A, example #3 *"He threw around it"* is ungrammatical when the pronoun "it" is unstressed; though it can be grammatical if it is used in an appropriate context, one which has "it" stressed.)

---

Note that the grammatical explanation given here is using the grammar framework of the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*.

Comment: Could it be the case that "to throw around the slipper" requires more than one actor? Let's go outside and throw the ball (or slipper) around?

Comment: @CarSmack I could *throw a football around* by myself if I'm bored, and I have done that. And if it was suggested to me to do that, because no one wants to play with me, then I could say, *"Sure, I'll throw it around by myself"*. If a parent later asked what I did all afternoon by myself, I could reply, *"I borrowed my brother's football and threw it around"*.

Comment: +1 Is this because  *it* is very short, and *a slipper* is a bit longer? We don't like pronouns inside these kind of verb + prep combinations? Btw, sorry I didn't get round to your *"as well as"* question. I thought my functions post was causing a stink! (still going on!) ... I've put a nice Pullum quote in an answer post there btw. I'll see if I can do something helpful and fun with *as well as* - but no promises!

Comment: I've never thrown around a baseball by myself. And one can certainly throw things around and *not* fetch them. The shoe is apparently only one of the items he threw around, meaning to scatter. If he fetched his show to throw it around again, it means he "scattered" his shoe more than once.

Comment: @δοῦλος "scattered"? I think of scattered as being more appropriate with a quantity of stuff or items, such as grain, *"He scattered the chicken feed around the cage"*, or ashes, or whatever. But with one item, like a football, or slipper, I don't think it can be scattered about.

Comment: A single slipper cannot be scattered by throwing it around.  It has to be broken into smaller pieces before it can be scattered.